# How to delete the Mail Programmatically in IMAP or POP using C#

Tags: c#, email, imap, tcpclient

This is my code to delete the mail. But, it doest working,

```
 public object Delete(int index)
        {
            StreamWriter.WriteLine("$ DELE {0}"+index);
            StreamWriter.Flush();
            return Response();    
        }
private string Response()
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int ret = NetworkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data).TrimEnd();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you adding these two items together:

```
StreamWriter.WriteLine("$ DELE {0}"+index);
```

Surely you mean something like this:

```
StreamWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("$ DELE {0}",index));
```

That said, this doesn't look like a valid IMAP command anyway. This looks more like POP, and even then, you shouldn't have a `$` in the command string. What specification are you following?

If you're connected to a POP3 server, the command should look something like this:

```
StreamWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("DELE {0}",index));
```

If you're connected to an IMAP server, I believe deleting requires first flagging the message as deleted, and then expunging it. Also, all commands in IMAP require a unique identifier which you will need to generate. From the spec:

> Each client command is prefixed with an identifier (typically a short alphanumeric string, e.g., A0001, A0002, etc.) called a "tag".  A different tag is generated by the client for each command.

Then to flag a message as deleted you would do something like this:

```
A003 STORE 35 +FLAGS (\Deleted)
```

Where `A003` is the tag prefix, and `35` is the sequence number of the message you want to delete. But then to permanently delete all flagged messages you'll also need to send and `EXPUNGE` command, that might look like this:

```
A004 EXPUNGE
```

Note that `EXPUNGE` will potentially result in message sequence numbers changing so you can't assume that the message associated with a particular sequence number will be the same after the `EXPUNGE` command has completed.

Comment: I see you've changed your title to say IMAP or POP, but you can't send POP commands to an IMAP server, or IMAP commands to a POP server. Which protocol is your server using? Sending a `DELE` command to an IMAP server is obviously going to return BAD command, because it's not a valid IMAP command, as I already pointed out in my answer.

Comment: Sorry ,i'm using IMAP server..i'm new to this topic..little bit confused...How can i delete mail

Comment: I've updated my answer with more details, but it's quite complicated for IMAP. Assumedly you have existing code that has got as far as authenticating with the server and would hopefully already be capable of generating a tag for each command you need to send.

Comment: i'm extractly following this link..http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-IMAP-CLIENT-b249d2e6

Comment: Interesting. It looks like they're using `$` as a tag and not bothering to make it unique. That's not technically valid by my reading of the spec, but if your server is happy with that, it makes things a lot easer. Where I've said to use a tag like `A003` or `A004` just use `$` instead.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30986/discussion-between-vino-and-james-holderness)

Comment: If you really intend to make an IMAP client, you should read the specification: RFC 3501.  There is no DELE command, and I'm really curious where you got it from.